# Auth0 saying connection didn't work beside all parameters are right

Tags: angular, auth0, social-authentication

[image: I'm getting this exception on auth0 console while testing]

Till yesterday it was working fine. no error was coming. but now I'm getting this exception and not able to find any clue regarding this.

Comment: Add more info than just an image and someone might actually be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the little detail you provided, my best guess is that a rule in your account has a problem. Try disabling it and run it again.